# what is generating the large gap in the site?

Tags: html, css

I am working on this site: beta.us.lt

And I have been playing with firebug for hours till now - cant find out what is generating the large gap by the footer. Can anybody inspect this issue or maybe somebody will have a good advice how to overcome this. Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are positioning `#wrapthecontent` 350px off the bottom:

```
#wrapthecontent {  (style.css line 492)
bottom: 350px;
...
```

Comment: But how to do it right? I still want to decrease th size of the wrapper. If I remove bottom: 350px from the #wrapthecontent when I will have a gap in between th wrapthecontent and the slider.

Answer (score 0):

it's

```
#wrapthecontent {
    bottom: 350px;
}
```

Comment: But how to do it right? I still want to decrease th size of the wrapper. If I remove bottom: 350px from the #wrapthecontent when I will have a gap in between th wrapthecontent and the slider.

Comment: I see it's already fixed. Consider accepting one of the answers.